# Email template not showing in full width in iPhone7.

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, email, email-templates, iphone

In **iPhone7** default email app Email template not showing in full width.

There is not any customization, this is `Magento 2.1.10` default email.

Email are showing as below screenshot.

Can someone help to resolve this issue. ?

[image]

Thanks..!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add below meta tag in your head of header email template.

```
 <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting" />
```

If you do not create header template then follow below steps:

**Dashboard - > Marketing -> Email Templates** add new template and select header template and click on Load template and add above meta tag.

Once you have created header template then assign you respective theme like below screenshot.
[image]

Thanks..!

Comment: Hooray this fixes it!! But 3 years later, why has this not been added to Magento?! iOS is one of the most used devices..! (Happens on 'blank theme' as well as 'Loo-meh'). And why does iOS squish it in like that in the first place, on such a seemingly simple email (a logo + some text)? I have never seen other emails do this in iOS mail. Is there some jankyness in the Magento email template or something? 